# Como puedo editar la configurador de WAMP sin entrar a phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

Queria dejarlo todo de fabrica porque quiero copiar las tablas de mi db pero no me deja entrar por estar tocando configuraciones para **activar las relaciones** , total, que me compensa mas borrar el wamp e intalar la ultima version de este, pero antes necesito eso, **copiar la BD que me interesa**.

¿Como puedo hacer un backup de mi tabla sin acceder a phpmyadmin?

Comment: Te vale con [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) ?  o te refieres mediante comandos de consola?

Comment: A ver Workbench no lo tengo instalado. Si pudiera hacerlo desde  consola o cualquier otro medio. Tampoco puedo acceder a phpmyadmin

Comment: mysqldump es tu solución -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: cuando intento hacer uso de `mysqldump` me dice que tengo algun error en la sintaxis, y cuando compruebo los comandos disponibles de `mysqldump` me dice lo mismo, como si no reconociera el comando